# spring upgradation to Spring 4 with controller mapping

Tags: java, spring

I am upgrading spring 3 to spring 4. Earlier I was using urlmapping in dispatcher-servlet.xml file to hit the controller class. The URL was invoked directly on controller and method name. Now when I am migrating it to Spring 4 I have used @RequestMapping in controller class, but not sure how to invoke method directly.

### Spring 3

dispatcher-servlet.xml ->

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>                
                <prop key="Test/*.do">TransactionController</prop>
</props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

So if I want to invoke method1 of TransactionController I directly invoke it as:
/Test/method1.do

### Spring 4

Now in Spring 4 I am using @RequestMapping so at class I have put below code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Test/*.do")
```

Now when I invoke /Test/method1.do then it gives 404 error.
Not sure how to do it at class level instead of putting the RequestMapping at method level.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after following
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-simpleurlhandlermapping-example/